# How to ignore a specific character in an Xpath?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to find the following element in the `DOM`
using selenium:

```
<button>
  App\u00ADly
</button>
```

As you can see that there is a soft hyphen character between the word Apply
I am wondering if there is any way to ignore this character and make that the following Xpath works.

```
//button[text()='Apply']
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is "\u00AD" a sequence of 6 characters in the DOM text node, or a way of showing us a single character in the DOM text?

If it's a single character, you can use `translate()` to eliminate it from the comparison: `//button[translate(., 'X', '') = 'Apply']` where X is the xAD character (I don't know what the escaping possibilities for this are in Selenium).

Comment: Genius!!! it was just what I was looking for, it worked. Thanks man.

Comment: @Andres, the convention in SO is to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick/check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`contains` is wrongly used in lot of places. There are more **xpath** function such as `starts-with` and `ends-with` (xpath v2.0).

But since **selenium** is tagged which uses `xpath v1.0` you won't be able to use `ends-with`

You can try something like :

```
//input[starts-with(text(),'App') and contains(text(),'ly')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the text `\u00AD` is dynamic or you want to skip. You can use `contains` in `xPath` along with `and` condition.

```
//button[contains(text(),'App') and contains(text(),'ly')]
```